# Jquery contains strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I whant to add class on specific string but problem is that string starts with number 0.

This is my code I whant to add just on "0  BAM" class but when I add this Jquery he add class on all divs that have 0 and BAM, Like first one "290 BAM"

```
<div class="views-field-commerce-price"> 290  BAM</div>
<div class="views-field-commerce-price"> 0  BAM</div>
<div class="views-field-commerce-price"> 223  BAM</div>
<div class="views-field-commerce-price"> 490  BAM</div>

  $('.views-field-commerce-price:contains("0  BAM")').addClass('item-3');
```

Thank You!

Comment: There is a space in-front of the text in the HTML code. You could add a `data-price="[N]"` attribute to the HTML element, and then select it using that: `...[data-price="0"]`. It would be more robust that selecting based on the text node.

Comment: jsbin after cleaning up spaces: https://jsbin.com/necinaxelu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need exact comparison, Here you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('.views-field-commerce-price').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim() == "0  BAM";
}).addClass('item-3');
```

Comment: One of the neatest js ever seen :)